# Query to get Publishers with IS or IT Book type

Tags: sql, database

I am having following database schema :

**AUTHORS**

```
Au_id
Au_lname
Au_fname
Phone
Address
City
State
Country
Postalcode
```

**PUBLISHERS**

```
Pub_id
Pub_name
City
State
```

**TITLES**

```
Title_id
Title, Type
Pub_id
Price
Advance
Total_sales
Notes
Pubdate
Contract
```

**TITLEAUTHOR**

```
Au_id
Title_id
```

**STORES**

```
Stor_id
Stor_name
Stor_address
City
State
Country
Postalcode
Payterms
```

**SALES**

```
Stor_id
Ord_num
Sdate
```

**SALESDETAIL**

```
Stor_id
Ord_num
Title_id
Qty
Discount
```

I need to find  `Publisher Id` and `Publisher Name` without duplicates, who have published books with highest sales on either IS or IT.

So i wrote this query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT PUBLISHERS.PUB_ID
    ,PUBLISHERS.PUB_NAME
FROM PUBLISHERS
INNER JOIN TITLES ON PUBLISHERS.PUB_ID = TITLES.PUB_ID
INNER JOIN SALESDETAIL ON TITLES.TITLE_ID = SALESDETAIL.TTITLE_ID
WHERE TITLES.TYPE = ‘IS’
    OR TITLES.TYPE = ‘IT’
    AND SALESDETAIL.QTY = MAX(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SALESDETAIL GROUP BY TITLE_ID);
```

Please help me if am doing it right ?

Comment: Should the duplicates not be counted at all or should they be grouped together?

Comment: @user3815511 Not counted

Comment: Could you please be more clear as to what you want for an answer? Do you want a more efficient way? Does the query you provide not work? Is there a syntax error? Because presume SALESDETAIL.TTITLE_ID is a typo.

Comment: which database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could just use windowed version of `MAX()` function if you are using SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
     p.PUB_ID
    ,p.PUB_NAME
    ,max(sd.qty) OVER (PARTITION BY p.pub_id,p.pub_name ORDER BY p.pub_name) 
              AS highest_sales
FROM PUBLISHERS p
INNER JOIN TITLES t ON p.PUB_ID = t.PUB_ID
INNER JOIN SALESDETAIL sd ON t.TITLE_ID = sd.TITLE_ID
WHERE (t.TYPE = 'IS'
    OR t.TYPE = 'IT');
```